# "outer" operation using dplyr/tidyr/purrr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Recently I stumbled uppon a problem where I need to compair pairwise differences of types:

```
sometypes <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, 2), 
                        type = paste0("t", 1:6), 
                        value1 = rnorm(6), 
                        value2 = rnorm(6))
```

Here I would like to compute the difference between value1 and value2 based on their type. I figured out to use `inner_join`:

```
#library(dplyr)
inner_join(select(sometypes, - value2), 
           select(sometypes, - value1), by = c("id")) %>%
  mutate(difference = value1 - value2)
```

Since I the actual example I have a chain of commands before and afterwards, I would like to make efficient use the `%>%` operator in:

```
# ... imagine some operators before
sometypes %>%
  (function(ds) inner_join(select(ds, - value2), 
                           select(ds, - value1), 
                           by = c("id"))) %>%
  mutate(difference = value1 - value2)
# ... imagine many operators afterwards
```

... and I would like to know if there is more concise way to describe it or is there any other consice solve this problem in `dplyr` (maybe using `map2_df` from `purrr`, but how?)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the 'correct' way is to use the `.` and curly braces:

```
sometypes %>%
  { inner_join(select(., - value2), 
             select(., - value1), 
             by = c("id")) } %>%
  mutate(difference = value1 - value2)
```

This stems from details on how the `%>%` operator works. You can read more about that in the `magrittr` documentation. Specifically, curly braces stop the left hand side from being used as the first function argument, and you can directly refer to the left hand side with `.`.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds reasonable, but does only changes the syntax. I'm interested whether there is a different, more consise appraoch.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, I misunderstood you question then.